# Reading coil and holding registers concurrently using pymodbus3

Tags: modbus, modbus-tcp, pymodbus, pymodbus3, pymodbustcp

I have a working code that can reads the coil status continuously using pymodbus3 library. The code is something like below. This is adapted from a basic sample and serves the purpose of looking for the coil status(address 0x01) change to "1" and perform the task as required without fail.

```html
def run_server(): 
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------- # 
    # initialize your data store 
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------- # 
    store = ModbusSlaveContext( 
        di=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100), 
        co=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100), 
        hr=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100), 
        ir=ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0, [17]*100)) 
        
    context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True) 

    interval = 3 
    server = ModbusTcpServer(context, identity=identity, address=('0.0.0.0', 1502)) 
    t = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever,name='server connection') 
   
    t.start() 
    loop = LoopingCall(f=updatevalues, a=server) 
    loop.start(interval, now=True) 
    reactor.run()

def updatevalues(a):
    rfuncode = 1
    wfuncode = 5
    slave_id = 0x01
    address = 0x02 
    contxt = a.context[slave_id]
    values = contxt.get_values(rfuncode, address, count=1)
    print(values[0])
    #below part is checking the coil status whether its 0 or 1 and perform the necessary task
    if(values[0]==1 or values[0]==17):
        #Do my stuff if this case is satisfied 
    
    #reset the coil back to "0" after the task is performed
    values = [0]
    contxt.set_values(wfuncode, address, values)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_server()
```

Now, I need to also monitor the holding registers (Address 400001 for e.g.) in parallel and read the value as well. Since the holding registers are already initialized in the run_server() function, I guess I don't have to do anything there. But I am not sure what to do in the updatevalues(a) function, so that the holding register can be monitored as well.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok,updating my staus. Right now I can read/write the holding registers after changing the function code to 3/6 respectively. However, the data I need to read is a number with 13 digits (Epoch time). Currently it is not able to read the full number using the code above. Any guidance on how can I go about receiving the full 13 digit number from my code would be much appreciated.